# AddComponent<> through extension method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

### Error: 'UnityEngine.GameObject' must be convertible to 'UnityEngine.Component'

I try to addcomponent through extension method which is non-monobehaviour class, I know it is wrong, but is there any solution to the problem?

```
public static void AddGameObject(this Transform go, int currentDepth, int depth)
{
    if (depth == currentDepth)
    {
        GameObject test = go.gameObject.AddComponent<GameObject>(); //error is here
        Debug.Log(go.name + " : " + currentDepth);
    }

    foreach (Transform child in go.transform)
    {
        child.AddGameObject(currentDepth + 1, depth);
    }
}
```

from monobehaviour class I call the extension method like this

> targetObject2.AddGameObject(0, 2);

basically what I want to achieve is addcomponent<> to all child through extension method.

Comment: You can inherit from an abstract `MonoBehavior`, but I think it can't be done as an extension method in a non-monohavior class.

Comment: i see you accepted my answer already, i've added some code for what you probably are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GameObjects aren't components, GameObjects are the objects on which you put components on. Thats why it says that you are trying to convert a GameObject into a Component.

So do you want to add a GameObject as a child? Do you want to create a new one?

You use AddComponent to add a Component(like MeshRenderer, BoxCollider, NetworkIdentity, ...) or one of your scripts(which are also components when they derive from Monobehaviour) to an already existing gameobject.

Let's say you want to add a Prefab you made as a child. What you do is to create a new GameObject and then set its parent like :

```
void AddChildGameObject(this GameObject go, GameObject childPrefab) {
    GameObject newChild = Instantiate(childPrefab) as GameObject;
    newChild.transform.parent = go.transform;
}
```

Comment: no wonder, im trying to add new GameObject as child. I manage to find the solution after your explanation. just add new GameObject and set the parent

Answer (score 1):

The right way to add new GameObjest as child is

```
public static void AddGameObject(this Transform go, int currentDepth, int depth)
{
    if (depth == currentDepth)
    {
        GameObject newChild = new GameObject("PRIMARY");
        newChild.transform.SetParent(go.transform);
        Debug.Log(go.name + " : " + currentDepth);
    }

    foreach (Transform child in go.transform)
    {
        child.AddGameObject(currentDepth + 1, depth);
    }
}
```

> basically what the code does is add new GameObject as child to all childs of gameObject base on depth.